# Is this sound software engineering practice for class construction?

Tags: python, class, oop, class-method

Is this a plausible and sound way to write a class where there is a  syntactic sugar @staticmethod that is used for the outside to interact with? Thanks.

```
###scrip1.py###
import SampleClass.method1 as method1

output = method1(input_var)

###script2.py###
class SampleClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 'var1'
        self.var2 = 'var2'

    @staticmethod
    def method1(input_var):
        # Syntactic Sugar method that outside uses
        sample_class = SampleClass()
        result = sample_class._method2(input_var)
        return result

    def _method2(self, input_var):
        # Main method executes the various steps.
        self.var4 = self._method3(input_var)
        return self._method4(self.var4)

    def _method3(self):
        pass

    def _method4(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Returning a value from `__init__` makes no sense (it has to be `None`). After you remove the `return`, it’s not clear what you’re asking.

Comment: and `self._method3` will fail if not indented as the other methods are.

Comment: Generally speaking, calling the constructor of a class should only ever return an instance of that class. So in your example I would expect first  `sampleInstance = SampleClass()` and then `output = sampleInstance.method1(input_var)`. 
Also try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for style and review questions like this. It seems like a better place for this kind of question.

Comment: @DanielW. in this case, it doesn't matter, because the return value of `__init__` is not what is returned by calling the constructor. So, it's just simply nonsense really, but I think you are addressing the point of what the OP is asking.

Comment: So is there a way to rewrite this code so that output = SampleClass(input_var)
would return the output of self.method1(input_var)? I don't want to write output = SampleClass().method1(input_var). Thanks.

Comment: "I don't want to" is a very poor reason to violate well-established conventions. If you don't have a *compelling* reason to avoid the simple and straightforward solution, you are only shooting yourself in the foot (as you yourself will probably be the first victim of this unpleasant surprise behavior). You can thank us later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering to both your question and your comment, yes it is possible to write such a code but I see no point in doing it:

```
class A:
    def __new__(cls, value):
        return cls.meth1(value)

    def meth1(value):
        return value + 1 

result = A(100)
print(result)

# output:
101
```

You can't store a reference to a class A instance because you get your method result instead of an A instance. And because of this, an existing `__init__`will not be called.

So if the instance just calculates something and gets discarded right away, what you want is to write a simple function, not a class. You are not storing state anywhere.
And if you look at it:

```
result = some_func(value)
```

looks exactly to what people expect when reading it, a function call.

So no, it is not a good practice unless you come up with a good use case for it (I can't remember one right now)

Also relevant for this question is the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=data%20model#basic-customization) to understand `__new__` and `__init__` behaviour.

Regarding your other comment below my answer:

defining `__init__` in a class to set the initial state (attribute values) of the (already) created instance happens all the time. But `__new__` has the different goal of customizing the *object creation*. The instance object does not exist yet when `__new__`is run (it is a constructor function).  `__new__` is rarely needed in Python unless you need things like a *singleton*, say a class `A` that always returns the very same object instance (of A) when called with `A()`. Normal user-defined classes usually return a new object on instantiation. You can check this with the `id()` builtin function. Another use case is when you create your own version (by subclassing) of an immutable type. Because it's immutable the value was already set and there is no way of changing the value inside `__init__` or later. Hence the need to act before that, adding code inside `__new__`. Using `__new__` without returning an object of the same class type (this is the *uncommon* case) has the addtional problem of not running `__init__`.

If you are just grouping lots of methods inside a class but there is still no state to store/manage in each instance (you notice this also by the absence of `self` use in the methods body), consider not using a class at all and organize these methods now turned into selfless functions in a module or package for import. Because it looks you are grouping just to organize related code.

If you stick to classes because there is state involved, consider breaking the class into smaller classes with no more than five to 7 methods. Think also of giving them some more structure by grouping some of the small classes in various modules/submodules and using subclasses, because a long plain list of small classes (or functions anyway) can be mentally difficult to follow.

This has nothing to do with `__new__` usage.

In summary, use the syntax of a call for a function call that returns a result (or None) or for an object instantiation by calling the class name. In this case the usual is to return an object of the intended type (the class called). Returning the result of a method usually involves returning a different type and that can look unexpected to the class user. There is a close use case to this where some coders return `self` from their methods to allow for train-like syntax:

```
 my_font = SomeFont().italic().bold()
```

Finally if you don't like `result = A().method(value)`, consider an alias:

```
func = A().method
...
result = func(value)
```

Note how you are left with no reference to the A() instance in your code.
If you need the reference split further the assignment:

```
a = A()
func = a.method
...
result = func(value)
```

If the reference to A() is not needed then you probably don't need the instance too, and the class is just grouping the methods. You can just write

```
func = A.method
result = func(value)
```

where selfless methods should be decorated with `@staticmethod` because there is no instance involved. Note also how static methods could be turned into simple functions outside classes.

### Edit:

I have setup an example similar to what you are trying to acomplish. It is also difficult to judge if having methods injecting results into the next method is the best choice for a multistep procedure. Because they share some state, they are coupled to each other and so can also inject errors to each other more easily. I assume you want to share some data between them that way (and that's why you are setting them up in a class):

So this an example class where a public method     builds the result by calling a chain of internal methods. All methods depend on object state, `self.offset` in this case, despite    getting an input value for calculations.

Because of this it makes sense that every method uses self to access the state. It also makes sense that you are able to instantiate different objects holding different configurations, so I see no use here for `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod`.

Initial instance configuration is done in `__init__` as usual.

```
# file: multistepinc.py

    def __init__(self, offset):
        self.offset = offset

    def result(self, value):
        return self._step1(value)

    def _step1(self, x):
        x = self._step2(x)
        return self.offset + 1 + x

    def _step2(self, x):
        x = self._step3(x)
        return self.offset + 2 + x

    def _step3(self, x):
        return self.offset + 3 + x

def get_multi_step_inc(offset):
    return MultiStepInc(offset).result
```

## --------

```
# file: multistepinc_example.py

from multistepinc import get_multi_step_inc

# get the result method of a configured
# MultiStepInc instance
# with offset = 10.

# Much like an object factory, but you
# mentioned to prefer to have the result
# method of the instance
# instead of the instance itself.
inc10 = get_multi_step_inc(10)

# invoke the inc10 method
result = inc10(1)
print(result)

# creating another instance with offset=2
inc2 = get_multi_step_inc(2)

result = inc2(1)
print(result)

# if you need to manipulate the object
# instance
# you have to (on file top)

from multistepinc import MultiStepInc

# and then
inc_obj = MultiStepInc(5)

# ...
# ... do something with your obj, then
result = inc_obj.result(1)
print(result)
```

---

Outputs:

```
37
13
22
```

Comment: Hi progmatico, thanks for the answer. That was very insightful. What if, class A() was a large class with many methods, and I wanted to call A(var), and it gives me an output. Should I still use a function or would this be a good choice to use __ new __? Thanks.

Comment: @BoPeng you are welcome, I edited my answer with some more ideas, regarding your comment.

Comment: @BoPeng I meant staticmethod not classmethod. Fixed.

Comment: Hi @progmatico, I modified the question according to your answer adding a  staticmethod that runs the various class methods that the outside can interact with. Can you see if that type of archicture is good practice? Thank you.

Comment: @BoPeng see my answer edit. Please don't change your questions after someone posts an answer. That may invalidate the answer meaning. Now that you did, just leave it, I think people can deduce what I am talking about. You can freely edit your answer usually to improve it, add more details etc. Avoid multiple different questions in one. Better to create a new question.