# member variable's reference count does not decrement after object was deleted

Tags: python, python-3.x, reference

**Background truths(?):** When python program exits, `gc`(`garbage collection`) works to collect memory in a common way `reference counting`.

So when an object was deleted, the reference count of it's member object should decrement 1. But I find the reference count does not minus 1, unless calling `del` in `__del__` function

```py
import sys

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'little b construct'
    def __del__(self):
        print(sys.getrefcount(self))
        print('little b was deleted')

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print('little a construct')
        self._b = B()

    def __del__(self):
        # del self._b   # makes B' reference minus 1
        print('little a was deleted')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
```

**Result:**

```
# without del self._b
little a construct
little a was deleted
4
little b was deleted
```

```
# with del self._b
little a construct
3
little b was deleted
little a was deleted
```

Question:

1. Why B's reference count does not minus 1 automatically after A was deleted?
2. what B's reference count `4` composed of?

Thanks for your help

Comment: **Key point:** why does a's destruction not bring a reduction in b's reference count. The reference **a._b** isn't deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simplified your example to make it easier for mentally counting the references.

What happens is that you have to count a reference for the object, another for the self inside the method, but also other references for the same object in the arguments of any function call running at the moment you invoke the `sys.getrefcount`, including that function too, because it also holds a copy of the reference in its own local scope.

So what you are missing is that calling functions, that require the object passed as argument, makes new names to be bound to the formal parameters in the local function/method scope. There is always a +1 offset, even when you just have a name pointing the object, exactly because of this new local reference inside `sys.getrefcount`:

```
import sys

class B():
    def __init__(self):
        print('setting up b...')
    def counter(self):
        return sys.getrefcount(self)

class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print('setting up a...')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    b = B()
    print(sys.getrefcount(a))
    print(sys.getrefcount(b))

    print(b, b.counter())  # 5 refs to b. Why 5?
    print(b, B.counter(b)) # Because this is what really happens.
    print(b.counter(), b ) # 4 refs to b

    print(b,b,b.counter()) # 6 refs to b
```

Output:

```
setting up a...
setting up b...
2
2
<__main__.B object at 0x7f11df905940> 5
4 <__main__.B object at 0x7f11df905940>
<__main__.B object at 0x7f11df905940> <__main__.B object at 0x7f11df905940> 6
```

Apart from this `__init__` is not a constructor, that's `__new__` that you usually don't need, `__init__` setups the object that is already created and accessible via `self`, see another answer of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56998151/is-this-sound-software-engineering-practice-for-class-construction/57014747#57014747), and `__del__` is usually not needed also, unless you need some special resource cleanup just before object destruction (destroying contained objects is not needed).

Finally del *does not delete* an object it just removes a name that binds to it; it decreases the refcount and after refcount reaches 0 it eventually gets collected by the GC.

My explanation to Q1 is that `a` still exists. As mentioned in your comment link to `__del__` docs, `__del__` is a finalizer not a destructor. Refcount being `0` means `__del__` is invoked, does not mean the object gets destroyed, and `__del__`does not destroy it. So the messages you print are not accurate (to the destruction moment). It will be destroyed by the GC, but you don't know exactly when (it is not specified in the language, depends on implementation).

Experiment replacing the statement

```
a = A()
```

by just

```
A()
```

Then no reference to A() object is kept, and this also decreases your refcount of `b` by one (while maintaining the rest of the output the same), meaning that there is no more `a._b`. So it should be the existance of `a` in memory with `a._b` that explains this 4 instead of 3. `a`is still alive when the `B.__del__` is running. The same happens (count decrease of b) if you instead add a `del a` as the last statement.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, but that only answered part of Q2. In your example, we could find line 6 of the result said refcount of B object is 4. I think 4 = 1(b) + 1(counter(self) argument) + 1(sys.getrefcount(self) argument) + ?, what's missing a reference? Thanks

Comment: Additional, what's your opinion regarding question 1, I don't understand why after a was deleted and a's reference to b should disappear, b's refercount should minus 1, but it isn't, it is still 4.

Comment: @wanncy: you *print* that `a` was deleted, but it wasn't yet.

Comment: thanks. yes, `del` only decreases the refcount. But I want to know after a' `__del__` functions finished, `a` was not deleted? It is called automatically when all references to the object are gone. And after a's `__del__` function is executed, object A was deleted.(refer [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__)) object B's refcount in my first result should be 3 not 4.